# can not pass two selector id in waitforselector with or condition in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, automation, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

```
await page.waitForSelector('#msg5',{waitUntil: '#msg5', timeout: 0});
```

is my code

I want my selector to wait for either #msg5 or #msg1, What is the easiest method to achieve that?

The below is what I tried and it did not work

```
await page.waitForSelector(/'#msg5'|'#msg1'/,{waitUntil: /'#msg5'|'#msg1'/, timeout: 0});
```

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49946728/puppeteer-waitforselector-on-multiple-selectors

Comment: It have multiple selectors there it do not answer how to pass the 'or' in selector I might be wrong because I am newbie