# How can I use page.waitForSelector in Playwright for one of two selectors?

Tags: playwright

I am trying to await a div that has one of two possible ids, `div#abc` or `div#efg`.

I can await `div#abc` like this:

```
    await this.page.waitForSelector('div#abc');
```

But how can I tell Playwright that I also want the step to pass if `div#efg` is present?

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77128725

Comment: In the above linked post playwright Or operator is discussed in detail which is native playwright solution to this problem,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Like with Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64451797), Playwright selectors can be standard CSS, so just add a comma between the selectors:

```
await this.page.waitForSelector('div#abc, div#efg');
```

Answer (score 3):

More general solution that works for any number of async operations:

```
const firstResolvedPromiseResult = await Promise.race([
  this.page.waitForSelector('div#abc'),
  this.page.waitForSelector('div#efg'),
]);
```

But the accepted solution is simpler for this use case.

Comment: Note: the loosing promise will trigger a timeout error.

Comment: @sn0wtroopeer Are you sure? I tried a simple example where the losing selector never exists, and it didn't throw. If they did, you could always slap `.catch(() => {})` on each promise, but I don't think this is necessary. `Promise.race` will throw if the first finished promise happens to reject, but if all of the timeouts are the same for its promises and one resolves, no throw will occur.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply use Locator [OR](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-or) natively :

```
await this.page.waitForSelector(locatorA.or(locatorB))
```