# Playwright's Or operator may match both elements

Tags: playwright

I'm trying to use the recent [`Or`](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/locators#matching-one-of-the-two-alternative-locators) operator.

C# code but idea applies to any Playwright language:

```cs
var newLocator = someLocator.Locator(".foo").Or(someLocator.Locator(".bar"));
```

I expect it to match `".foo"`, and if that does not exist then to match `".bar"`. If both exist then I expect it to match `".foo"` (the first one).

However *when both exist then it matches both*, and if I use that locator I'll get a strict mode violation (I need to use the first match to avoid that).

That is very surprising - I expect "or" to mean *"either this or that"* rather than "both".

Am I misunderstanding the use case for this API?

Comment: Are any of those locators or their parent locators live inside iframes?

Comment: @VishalAggarwal No, just normal DOM elements.

Comment: @Ionix    Great question as usual!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Playwright locators are [strict](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#strictness) "by design". It means that it expects
> exactly one locator to resolve to a visible element when it expects it
> to match condition (isVisible).

In your case, you should add nth(0) in the last to let playwright know that you are interested in any (first) match:

```
await expect(lA.or(lB).nth(0)).toBeVisible();
```

Reference:https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/26842#issuecomment-1706939112

Comment: I also asked on the [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/discussions/27143). I think naming it "or" is a surprising design choice. But, it's good that there's a simple way (nth) to solve this. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: I added a documentation [request](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/27169) to the repo.

Comment: I think naming it 'or' is correct however there are two conflicting requirements at play here - one locators are strict , they should match only single element and second is 'or' needs to match two elements at the same time .

Comment: The fact we need to select `.nth` or `.first` etc still isn't obvious in the updated documentation... Thanks for raising it @lonix, and for the answer @vishal-aggarwal