# playwright - how to use locator depends on device in test?

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I want to use different locator to mobile and desktop device in PageObject not in test.spec..

how to get browserName ?

```
async login(phoneNumber: string, smsPassword: string): Promise<void> {
  await this.buttonLogin.click();

  if (isMobile ){
    await this.buttonLoginNavModal2.click();
  } else {
    await this.buttonLoginNavModal.click();
  }

  await this.inputPhoneNumber.fill(phoneNumber);
  await LocatorHelper.pressEnter(this.inputPhoneNumber);
  await this.inputSmsPassword.fill(smsPassword);
  await LocatorHelper.pressEnter(this.inputSmsPassword);
}
```

get browserName from testConfig and depends on device use correct locator

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using browsername to check if it is a mobile device, you can access and use the [isMobile](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions#test-options-is-mobile) testoption like this:

```js
test('Test', async ({ page, isMobile }) => {
  if (isMobile)) {
    this.buttonLoginNavModalFirstLocator.click();
  } else {
    this.buttonLoginNavModalSecondLocator.click();
  }
});
```

EDIT: Using in POM:

PageObject file, add isMobile to constructor:

```js
import { Locator, Page } from "@playwright/test";

export class MyPage {
  readonly page: Page;
  readonly buttonLoginNavModal: Locator;

  constructor(page: Page, isMobile: boolean) {
    this.page = page;
    this.buttonLoginNavModal = isMobile
      ? page.getByRole("button", {name: 'mobile'})
      : page.getByRole("button", {name: 'desktop'});
  }
}
```

Using in test:

```js
test("Test", async ({ page, isMobile }) => {
  const myPage = new MyPage(page, isMobile);
  await myPage.buttonLoginNavModal.click()
});
```

Comment: I would like to use in PageObject ,  how Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

#### There is no need to define 'isMobile' all over the codebase

> You can simply handle it on locator lever using OR condition. Then the
> same locator will work everywhere without any conditional code:

```
const submitBtn = page.locator('xpath1 | xpath2')
await expect(submitBtn)).toBeVisible()
```

#### Using Page Object Model without any conditional code:

```
 import { Locator, Page } from "@playwright/test";
    
    export class MyPage {
      readonly page: Page;
      readonly buttonLoginNavModal: Locator;
    
      constructor(page: Page) {
        this.page = page;
        this.buttonLoginNavModal = page.locator('xpath1 | xpath2')
          
      }
    }
    
    //in test
    
    test("Test", async ({ page}) => {
      const myPage = new MyPage(page);
      await myPage.buttonLoginNavModal.click()
    });
```

Or I can use playwright 'or' locator itself as well for that purpose.

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-or
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77128725/1831456

Comment: I would like to use in PageObject , how Can I do this?

Comment: @BeatzTomek beauty of this approach is , you don't need to change anything and you can use it with page objects as is and without any conditional statements as required in other answer.

Comment: @BeatzTomek please see the complete solution using page object.