How to check if an element is visible?
I want to check if an element is visible. If so, I want to click on it. If not, I want to check if another html element is available and click on it. How can I do this using playwright?
The html element in question has test id "create-btn"

Does this answer your question? Check if element is visible in Playwright

See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77128725

See above shared link - basically you need playwright OR locator.

It's a good idea to break your problem into distinct, easily searchable, steps:

Select element by test id (page.getByTestId("create-btn"))
Click it. (page.getByTestId("create-btn").click())

As the docs state, clicking (and many other actions) auto-wait for actionability by default, which includes being visible in the viewport and not behind another element.
Here's a minimal example:
import {test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.42.1

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<button style="visibility: hidden;" data-testid="create-btn">click me</button>
<script>
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector("button").style.visibility = "visible";
}, 4000);
</script>
</body></html>`;

test("create-btn can be clicked", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.getByTestId("create-btn").click();
});

If you want to click a different button if the first one never shows up, you can extend the code to do this with a try/catch:
const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<button style="visibility: hidden;" data-testid="menu-btn">click me</button>
<script>
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector("button").style.visibility = "visible";
}, 4000);
</script>
</body></html>`;

test("create-btn or menu-btn can be clicked", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  try {
    await page.getByTestId("create-btn").click({timeout: 5_000});
  } catch (err) {
    await page.getByTestId("menu-btn").click();
  }
});

.or(), the CSS comma operator (,) and Promise.race might also be useful if you want to click the first visible of multiple buttons:
test("create-btn or menu-btn can be clicked", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);

  await page.getByTestId("create-btn")
    .or(page.getByTestId("menu-btn")).click();

  await page.locator(
    '[data-testid="create-btn"],[data-testid="menu-btn"]'
  ).click();

  await Promise.race([
    page.getByTestId("create-btn").click(),
    page.getByTestId("menu-btn").click(),
  ]);
});

If you don't want to auto-wait, you can use .isVisible() to run an immediate check:
const createBtn = page.getByTestId("create-btn");
if (await createBtn.isVisible()) {
  await createBtn.click();
}

const menuBtn = page.getByTestId("menu-btn");
if (await menuBtn.isVisible()) {
  await menuBtn.click();
}

But conditions and nondeterminism aren't generally good practice in tests.

this will give me an error if create-btn is not visible. I want to check if its visible for 60 seconds first. if not, click on menu-btn

You can catch the throw and click on menu-btn. I don't suggest doing this, though--generally, you want to avoid conditionals in tests and web scraping (especially tests). 60 seconds is a long wait, generally you want to make a decision much faster than that. Knowing your actual use case would be useful. Please add details to your question.
